# Why aggregation doesn’t return exact data in my DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I made a lookup with two collections existing in my db, result of this lookup I want to join with another collection in my db, So I could implement this query with success but returned docs are more than data existing in my db for example I have 266 records, After the query I got 524 I don’t know where they come . 
HINT : when I use simple find() I got correct result but with this aggregation I got more records
Here is my function shown below :

```
let settlement = await this.profileModel.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        bindedSuperAdmin: name,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'tpes',
        localField: 'nameUser',
        foreignField: 'merchantName',
        as: 'tpesBySite',
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'settlements',
        localField: 'tpesBySite.terminalId',
        foreignField: 'terminalID',
        as: 'settlementsByUser',
        pipeline: [
          {
            $sort: {
              transactionDate: -1,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },

    { $unwind: '$tpesBySite' },

    { $unwind: '$settlementsByUser' },
    { $unwind: '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions' },
    {
      $project: {
        bReconcileError: '$settlementsByUser.bReconcileError',
        batchNumber: '$settlementsByUser.batchNumber',
        btransfered: '$settlementsByUser.btransfered',
        countryCode: '$settlementsByUser.countryCode',
        currencyCode: '$settlementsByUser.currencyCode',
        merchantID: '$settlementsByUser.merchantID',
        nSettlementAmount: '$settlementsByUser.nSettlementAmount',
        onlineMessageMACerror: '$settlementsByUser.onlineMessageMACerror',
        reconciliationAdviceRRN:
          '$settlementsByUser.reconciliationAdviceRRN',
        reconciliationApprovalCode:
          '$settlementsByUser.reconciliationApprovalCode',
        settledTransactions: [
          {
            appName: '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions.appName',
            cardInputMethod:
              '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions.cardInputMethod',
            cardPAN_PCI:
              '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions.cardPAN_PCI',
            networkName:
              '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions.networkName',
            onlineApprovalCode:
              '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions.onlineApprovalCode',
            onlineRetrievalReferenceNumber:
              '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions.onlineRetrievalReferenceNumber',
            transactionAmount:
              '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions.transactionAmount',
            transactionDate:
              '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions.transactionDate',
            transactionTime:
              '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions.transactionTime',
            transactionType:
              '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions.transactionType',
          },
        ],

        settlementAmount: '$settlementsByUser.settlementAmount',
        settlementDate: '$settlementsByUser.settlementDate',
        settlementTime: '$settlementsByUser.settlementTime',
        terminalID: '$settlementsByUser.terminalID',
        traceNumber: '$settlementsByUser.traceNumber',
        uniqueID: '$settlementsByUser.uniqueID',
      },
    },
  ]);
  console.log('settlement from service ', settlement.length);

  return settlement;
```

I’m really confused, it’s my first time I face this kind of error anyone could help me please ?

Comment: You will get duplicate top level (parent) documents after $unwind if the result of $lookup is an array with multiple elements

Comment: How can I resolve it please ?

Comment: You'll have to review the actual output to see how the data ends up with duplicates. I suggest you try to see output of each aggregation stage

Comment: Yes it returns same data many times why ?

Comment: Try to output the at the 2nd and 3rd step, you may see that the output of $lookup contains arrays with multiple elements. $unwind will deconstruct that array. See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: no I guess this line  { $unwind: '$settlementsByUser.settledTransactions' }, was the problem take a look here my question more details https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/what-is-the-best-way-to-lookup-join-one-to-many-collections-with-array-of-references-in-mongodb/172793

Comment: But how can I unwind a nested array without duplicating the data ?

Comment: Getting duplicate data is part of $unwind. What do you actually want to use $unwind for?

Comment: the link I put contains my question detailed